# PHP Lookbehind Regex

Tags: php, regex, lookbehind

I am looking for not matching previous word..
Example: "PrevNot MyWord";

Now below code can check last word only if one space is in between.

```
(?<!PrevNot\s)MyWord
```

But it not working if there are more then one space..

Example: "PrevNot     MyWord"
How can i check last not match by ignoring space?

Comment: Lookbehinds have to be fixed size, you can't have a variable number of spaces.

Comment: You will need to use `(?<!PrevNot)\s+MyWord` and just trim the result when you extract it.

Comment: okay thanks. I got it